# spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure 2.1.0.RELEASE not exists in maven central

Tags: spring-boot

There is no mention in release notes that the artifact is deleted (2.1.0.RC1 exists in Spring repository)

Maybe something goes wrong with release 2.1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a separate dependency, please download it from

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is that means that versions Spring Boot and spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure are not related and previous Spring Boot release has the same version by accident?

Comment: As far as I know, spring security related dependencies have always been separate to boot.